# Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder - Concurrency

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, cloud-foundry

I built a spring boot kinesis consumer with the following components:

- spring boot (version - 2.1.2.RELEASE)
- spring cloud (version - Greenwich.RELEASE)
- spring cloud stream kinesis binder (version - 1.1.0.RELEASE)

I consume events from a **kinesis stream with 1 shard**. Also this spring boot consumer application is running in **Pivotal Cloud Foundry Platform**.

I tried the scenario locally (with kinesalite) and in PCF (with a kinesis stream) before posting this question. Can you please confirm whether my understanding is right? I went through the spring cloud stream documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc). Though the documentation is exhaustive, concurrency and high availability is not explained in detail.

Let’s say I have 3 instances of the consumer deployed to PCF (by setting the instances attribute to 3 in the **manifest.yml** file which is used during cf push).

**All 3 instances have the below properties**:

spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.concurrency=5

spring.cloud.stream.bindings..group=my-consumer-group

spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.checkpoint.table=my-metadata-dynamodb-table

spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.binder.locks.table=my-locks-dynamodb-table

Let’s say the events were sent to kinesis by the producer in this order

event5 (most recent event in the stream) - event4 - event3 - event2 - event1 (first event in the stream)

For such a configuration, I have explained my understanding below. Can you confirm whether this is right?

1. Only one instance of the consumer is active at a given point of time and it will process all the events sent to the kinesis stream (as the stream has only one shard). One of the other 2 instances will take control only when the primary instance is down. This configuration is to ensure high availability and retain ordering of messages.
2. Since the number of instances is set at the manifest.yml for PCF, I need not worry about setting spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount or spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.instanceCount properties.
3. 5 consumer threads are active (since concurrency is set to 5) when the spring boot consumer is started/launched. Now the events are consumed in the order explained above. Thread1 picks up event1. When thread1 is still actively processing event1, the other thread just picks and starts processing the next event from the stream (thread2 process event2 and so on...). Though the order of events are retained in this case (event 1 is always picked up before event2 and so on....), there is no guarantee that thread1 will finish processing event1 before thread 2.
4. When all the 5 threads are busy processing the 5 events in the stream, if new events say event6 and event7 comes in, the consumer has to wait for a thread to become available. Say, thread3 is done processing event3 and other threads are still busy processing events, thread3 will pick up event6 and start processing but event7 is still not picked up as there are no available threads.
5. By default concurrency is set to 1. If your business requirement demands you to complete processing the first event before picking up the next, then concurrency should be 1. You are compromising the throughput in this case. You can only consume one event at a time. But if throughput is important and you want to process more than one event at a given point of time, then the concurrency should be set to a desired value. Increasing the number of shards is also an option but as a consumer if you cannot demand for an increase, this is your best bet to achieve parallelism/throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see `concurrency` option JavaDocs in the `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`:

```
/**
 * The maximum number of concurrent {@link ConsumerInvoker}s running.
 * The {@link ShardConsumer}s are evenly distributed between {@link ConsumerInvoker}s.
 * Messages from within the same shard will be processed sequentially.
 * In other words each shard is tied with the particular thread.
 * By default the concurrency is unlimited and shard
 * is processed in the {@link #consumerExecutor} directly.
 * @param concurrency the concurrency maximum number
 */
public void setConcurrency(int concurrency) {
```

So, since you have only one shard in that one stream, there is going to be only one active thread which iterates over `ShardIterator`s on that single shard.

The point is that we always have to process records from a single shard in a single thread. This way we guarantee a proper order, plus checkpoint is done for the highest sequence number.

Please, investigate more what is AWS Kinesis and how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the response Artem. What is significance of setting consumer concurrency to a value greater than 1 when a kinesis stream has 1 shard? Nothing? Also can you tell me whether I should worry about the instanceCount if it is a PCF app and the number of instances are set at the manifest level? As long as all the three instances use the same consumer group name, checkpoint table and locks table I am all set from a high availability perspective right?

Comment: Yes, if you use only one shard at all, the `concurrency` is ignored. In case of `instanceCount` on PCF it only makes sense for the high availability as you noticed, nothing more. The `concurrency` starts to play role when you have more than 1 shard or use several streams to consume.

Comment: Thanks Artem. That answers all my questions. From AWS Kinesis standpoint I know that parallelism or high throughput can be achieved only if you have more than 1 shard. Concurrency attribute in the binder threw me off a bit. It gave me a wrong assumption that multiple threads would process that single shard in parallel and I can use that if order is not important. Your detailed explanation clarifies that for me and concurrency has no significance since I have 1 shard. I need HA anyway and I know it is not tied to concurrency. I will set the instances at manifest level and remove concurrency.

Comment: Did that. Thanks again

Comment: We're running horizontally scaled services using replicas in Docker Swarm. If I run 3 replicas of a service that consume from 1 stream with 3 shards and I set ```spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<bindingTarget>.consumer.concurrency``` to 3, will each of my services only consume from 1 shard? In other words, will service 1 always consume from shard 1, service 2 from shard 2, and so on? I'm still not understanding completely what the concurrency property provides for when consuming more than 1 shard and whether we also need to specify instanceCount and instanceIndex properties to run in HA mode.